# Tracking arduino devices on android phone using iBeacons

Tags: android, google-maps, arduino, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have an arduino robot and I wish to track its location on an indoor map on my android phone. I can create an indoor map and upload it to google maps. Depending on its location in the building the android would issue commands to the arduino robot to navigate to a specific area in the building or carry out some other task. How can I track its location at all times inside a building? If I set up beacons through out the building, I can make the arduino device advertise itself to these beacons.....then I would somehow need the beacons to communicate the arduino device location back to the android phone. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: 'I can make the arduino device advertise itself to these beacons.....'. Even if you could let the arduino advertise itself it would not help as the ibeacons would not listen. IBeacons advertise themselfes. It's one way communicarion though. 'the beacons to communicate the arduino device location back to the android phone.'. Beacons will not do that for you. How would you program them? No. The arduino device should send it's position to your Android device.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In that case what is the point of beacons? If the arduino can communicate with android and vice versa what would the need for beacons be?

Comment: You want to use them isn't it? And you did not a little search on them? You could use them to know the position of your arduino within a building for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Building something that does this with iBeacons is not impossible, but it is a very advanced and complex project.  Beacons would only be a very small building block of a complex system that does this.

Two basic approaches:

1. Place beacon transmitters all around the room, then write beacon scanning software on the Arduino that sends info to a web service about the beacon signals detected.  The web service would crunch the numbers and calculate the position.
2. You could turn the Arduino into a beacon transmitter and place beacon scanners around the room.  The scanners would report the signals from the Arduino transmitter to the sever, which would again crunch the numbers and calculate the position.

Either way, this is a very complex system to build.  It is not something where a solution can provided in this forum.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This will defn help me in the right direction. I didn't realize it was so hard to get exact position of an item within a building. I did a bit more research after reading your post and apparently you're supposed to use various algorithms to estimate location based on the beacon readings (algorithms like Least-Squares, Lateration, Angulation, etc).